# To display selected href to a block using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

```
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <ul class="list-group text-left">
   <a href="#" class="list-group-item" ng-click="selectedIndex = $index" ng-                 repeat="field in Data">
       {{ field.name }}</a>
  </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
  <div ng-show="selectedIndex == $index" ng-repeat="field in Data">
   <div class="panel panel-primary" ng-repeat="scenario in field.scenarios track by $index">
  <div class="panel-heading ">
    {{ scenario.name }}
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I need to select the field.name in href to display the corresponding selected field as a block in same page. But it is always redirecting to # and there is no data to display.
Please advice is it possible to display the value for the selected field in same page.

Comment: Can you please elaborate ?? are you using `ng-route` or `ui-router` ?? or nothing?

Comment: In the href give your page url. It wont escape to the other page

Comment: I am using ngRoute but there I need to display data from below block for the selected from outer href.

Comment: Can you write your js code. This is only html.